# Generate stream network for every pixel of flow direction as a polyline shapefile based on the raster cell value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcobjects, saga

I have a flow direction raster (coded with ESRI flow directional encoding scheme)  and I want to generate stream network for every grid cell of flow direction raster as a polyline feature based on the pixel value in the flow direction without using the flow accumulation raster and threshold value for stream network generation. Is there any tools or package available to do that? I have tried using SAGA GIS for the purpose (Terrain analysis-channels-D8 flow analysis which is found only in earlier version of SAGA GIS) but it does not generate stream network for every grid cell. Sometimes, the stream network for multiple cells are combined to give only one polyline feature in SAGA.

Comment: do you have a reason for not wanting to use flow accumulation and threshold? If you did go that route, it would only require setting a threshold of 1 to get what you're looking for.

Comment: As far as a polyline goes, the output from hydrology tools is always a raster. you need to convert that to vector if you want polylines.  You can do this in ArcGIS but this type of work is best done in QGIS, GRASS, SAGA (GRASS and SAGA tools can be accessed from inside QGIS). Note that some SAGA and GRASS tools have not been fully converted to the new Python version QGIS 3 uses so you may want to run these tools in the previous legacy 2.18 version.